# Tag Feature in edittext after typing @ like facebook/instagram

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I want to have feature in my edittext, where when you type '@' u will be shown suggetions from your friend list to tag.

I have three plans for doing that:

1) add a `textwatcher` to my `edittext` and on seeing '@' inflate a `autocompletetextView` over it, so i can show the suggestions from friend list. (haven't tried that)

2) have a `autocompletetextView` instead of `edittext` in the first place and make it show suggestions only when you type '@'(haven't tried, don't know how it will work)

3) use some library (tried [TagEditText]][1](https://github.com/RyPope/TagEditText), didn't work.

What will be the appropriate way to that?

Comment: I think [Social View](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/socialview) is what you're searching for... or try [Spy Glass](https://github.com/linkedin/Spyglass). Seeing the implementation, try Social View first, seems easy and better.

Comment: thank you very much,  don't know i was not able to find that library.

Comment: Glad it helped mate & BTW nice description :).